# Android Location Services not working

Tags: android, geolocation

Here goes: I've spent all night scouring the internet, especially StackOverflow, trying to figure out why I can't get basic Location Services working in Android. I have tried in a variety of emulated environments, from Android 1.6 up to Android 4, all with GPS services emulated, as well as on an actual Android 2.2.2 Device. Location is always returned as null, I've tried at least seven different downloadable sample projects, using them verbatim, and getting the same results.

Obviously, I'm missing something key. If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

com.mytestproject.android:

```
package com.mytestproject.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.mytestproject.android.R;
public class MyTestProject extends Activity {
private TextView mytext;
private LocationManager locmgr = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.b.mytext);

    //grab the location manager service
    locmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mytext.setText("waiting for location");
}

//Start a location listener
LocationListener onLocationChange=new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        //sets and displays the lat/long when a location is provided
        String latlong = "Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Long: " + loc.getLongitude();   
        mytext.setText(latlong);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
    Bundle extras) {
    // required for interface, not used
    }
};

//pauses listener while app is inactive
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locmgr.removeUpdates(onLocationChange);
}

//reactivates listener when app is resumed
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);
}
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/mytext"  
android:textSize="15pt"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.johnandbrian.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyTestProject"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you saying that `onLocationChanged()` method _is_ getting called but `loc.getLatitude()` / `getLongitude()` are returning `null`?

Comment: I added some code to set mytext whenever something is called. It looks like onResume and onPause get called correctly, but onLocationChange does not.

Comment: Where are you instantiating the location listener? (The `onLocationChange` object could be named better.) It's not enclosed by `onCreate()`. Copy/paste error?

Comment: As per @Hesham-Saeed's suggestion, I added this line to onCreate():
`locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);`

But that didn't help.

Comment: That's not the question. Where are you *instantiating* the location listener? If it's in an `Activity` but not within the `onCreate()` or one of the other standard `Activity` methods, then the code never runs because the framework never calls it.

Comment: @Brizian you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

add this to `onCreate()` function,

```
locmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,10000.0f,onLocationChange);
```

Comment: Ok, try to remove the onLocationChange listener, and make the class implments LocationListener and add the function onLocationChanged() in the class with @Override above it then use 'this' instead of onLocationChange [This is only re-structuring of the code, maybe it helps]

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Comment: Try to use 0 instead of 10000.0f in the requestLocationUpdates() function

Answer (score 0):

If `onLocationChanged()` isn't even being called, even with sample projects, then I don't think "location is always null" is an accurate description of the problem. `onLocationChanged()` is only called when the location *changes*. So it sounds like you are (a) not injecting mock locations or otherwise driving the location engine when using the emulator, and (b) not moving around enough on the real device. I suggest loading a sample project onto the real device, *going outside*, and moving around some (several 10s of meters). Put some breadcrumbs in the `onLocationChanged()` method (in the sample project) to verify that it's being called.

Comment: I just went for an eight block walk. I never got a notification that `onLocationChanged()` was being called.

Comment: Do the sample projects also set the `minDistance` argument of `requestLocationUpdates()` to 100,000 meters? @Hesham Saeed 's suggestion to set `minDistance` to a low value is a good one. Also, make sure the phone's settings are permitting GPS access. On my phone, this is at Settings -> Location & security -> Use GPS satellites